# Howto update duplicates in firebird?

Tags: sql, rdbms, firebird, firebird2.1

Searched google for "firebird update duplicates" and "firebird handle duplicate update" but did not get any stuff, that would solve my question; so i thought it would be a good idea to use this marvellous site for the first time :)
So how do i achieve mysql's "INSERT INTO asdf (x,y,z) VALUES ('a',1,2) ON DUPLICATE KEYS UPDATE z = 2"  in firebird?

thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm not mysql dialect expert, I don't know what the statement is supposed to do... can you explain in a way my grandmother understands it?

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE OR INSERT INTO <table or view> [(<column_list>)]
    VALUES (<value_list>)
    [MATCHING (<column_list>)]
    [RETURNING <column_list> [INTO <variable_list>]]
```

[Update or Insert](http://www.firebirdsql.org/rlsnotesh/rlsnotes210.html#rnfb210-updorinsrt)